# transition scale relative to parent

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am using `transition:scale(1.2)` to hide a `div` in the bottom left corner of the viewport.

[image: Current & desired results]

My current approach is scaling from the center as expected:

<kbd>**[Fiddle for 'CURRENTLY'](http://jsfiddle.net/RienNeVaPlus/mZtdb/)**</kbd>

I want to scale it as if the `div` would take up the whole screen:

<kbd>**[Fiddle for 'DESIRED'](http://jsfiddle.net/RienNeVaPlus/gZfbX/)**</kbd>

The above is done by scaling the whole `body`. But **instead of using another parent**, I was wondering if there is another way to tell CSS in which direction the scaling should occur.

How to use `transition:scale(1.2)` as seen in **DESIRED** without using a full-size div?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the transform-origin:

Something like this should be close to what you are looking for:

```
-webkit-transform-origin: 120% -40%;
```

<kbd>[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/gZfbX/1/)</kbd>

Modified CSS:

```
#clock {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:8%;
    left:7%;
    color:#fff;
    transition:all .8s;
    -webkit-transition:all .8s;
    transform-origin: 120% -40%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 120% -40%;
}

body {
    overflow:hidden;
}

body:hover #clock {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.2);
    transform:scale(1.2);
    opacity:0;
}
```

---

**Edit** Because you are using left/bottom percentage based positioning for the clock, this may be closer to the effect you are looking for.  Going back to a center based transform origin and transitioning left/bottom closer to the corner will provide a bit more of the affect that it is being scaled from the upper right corner of the parent.

<kbd>[Demo Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/gZfbX/3/)</kbd>

Modified CSS:

```
#clock {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:8%;
    left:7%;
    color:#fff;
    transition:all .8s;
    -webkit-transition:all .8s;
    transform-origin: center center;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
}

body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
body:hover #clock {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
    bottom: 1%;
    left: 0%;
    opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus I just noticed you are using percentage positioning - may have a solution for you...